# ajax can not send request and return values on dynamic input field except 1 row in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Below is my HTML code. I can only get value returned by ajax request in that id="sss" field.

My Problems are listed below with images:-

[image: Problem One Showing On Image]

[image: Problem Two Showing On Image]

```
<form id="dynamic2" action="<?= site_url('product/save') ?>" method="post">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody id="itemlist2" class="detailss">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <select id="select-product" class="form-control" data-cell="B1" name="product_name[]">
            <option value="">
            </option>
            <?php
              foreach ($product as $key ):
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $key['id']  ?>">
              <?php echo $key['product_name'] ?>
            </option>
            <?php  endforeach; ?>
          </select>
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="text" id="sss" data-cell="C1" name="price[]" class="form-control" value="">
        </td>

        <td>
          <input type="text" data-cell="D1" name="quantity[]" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" data-cell="E1" name="discount[]" class="form-control">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" data-cell="F1" name="total[]" 
            disabled="true" data-formula="(D1*C1)-(D1*C1*E1/100)"
            class="form-control">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  </table>
</form>
```

I am not getting value returned by ajax request in dynamically created input fields.

Here is my dynamically created input field jS code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $form = $('#dynamic2').calx();
        $('.addrowss').click(function() {

            $itemlist = $('#itemlist2');
            $counter = 5;
            var i = ++$counter;
            var tr = '<tr>' +
                '<td><select id="select-product" class="form-control" data-cell="B' + i + '" name="product_name[]"><option value=""></option><?php
                        foreach ($product as $key ):
                          ?><option value="<?php echo $key['product_name']  ?>"><?php echo $key['product_name'] ?></option><?php  endforeach; ?></select></td>'+
                '<td><input id="sss" type="text" data-cell="C' + i + '" name="price[]" class="form-control" value=""></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" data-cell="D' + i + '" name="quantity[]" class="form-control"></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" data-cell="E' + i + '" name="discount[]" class="form-control"></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" data-cell="F' + i + '" name="total[]" data-formula="(D' + i + '*C' + i + ')-(D' + i + '*C' + i + '*E' + i + '/100)"></td>' +
                '<td><a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a></td>' +
                '</tr>';
            $('.detailss').append(tr);
            $form.calx('update');
            $form.calx('getCell', 'G1').setFormula('SUM(F1:F' + i + ')');
        });

        $('body').delegate('.remove', 'click', function() {
            var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
            var c = confirm("Do you want to remove this ?");
            if (c) {
                tr.remove();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Ajax Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#select-product").change(function() {

      var id = $(this).val();
      //  alert(id);
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "<?php echo site_url('/product/view_data'); ?>",
        data: {
          "id": id
        },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
          var tmp = data.split(",");
          $('#sss').val(tmp[6]);
        }


      });
    });

  });

</script>
```

Product.php Controller

```
public function view_data()
{
  if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $this->load->model('Product_model');
    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $param = $this->Product_model->get_ajax_value($id);
    foreach($param as $a)
      echo $a.",";

    exit;      
  }    
}
```

Comment: Show images in question and run code through jsbeautifier.org to reduce some of the mess level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure why it isn't returning all the correct data. But here might be a step to help you debug you problem.

Add a console.log(data); To see what is being returned from the ajax call. Use the console of your browser to see this.

Change your code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

                  $("#select-product").change(function () {

                     var id = $(this).val();
                   //  alert(id);
                     $.ajax({
                          type: "GET",
                          url: "<?php echo site_url('/product/view_data'); ?>",
                          data: {"id":id},
                          cache: false,
                          success: function(data){
                              console.log(data); //this will show what is returned.
                               var tmp = data.split(",");
                               $('#sss').val(tmp[6]);
                           }


                      });
                  });

});
```

I understand this isn't the complete answer to your code. But it might put you on the right track to seeing what the server is returning to your client side code.

Comment: Sir, Nothing sows on console log when i create a dynamic filed and click on product selection box.

Comment: I'm only getting response from first row but not others rows created by dynamically.

Comment: Can you give us a screen shot?

Comment: I'm just getting value on first row.

Comment: @TPLMedia24 that is good to hear. What changes did you make that got it working?